# How to close navigation bar when I click on other contents in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a navigation bar it  works fine.

It consists of several tabs such as Home, about, services, contact.

But I want to close it when I click on the contents of the web page.

**Code:**

```js
(function() {

  var bodyEl = $('nav'),
    navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

  navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})();
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("nav").removeClass("active-nav");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #036;
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.active-nav {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-toggle-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #666;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 300px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.active-nav .content {
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}

.fa-bars {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <h1>This is content</h1>
</div>
```

How can I close my navigation bar, when I click on the other contents in the web page.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Deepshika. It would really help a lot if your code has some indentation. It makes it easier for us to read and helps you solve your problem faster.

Comment: now check out my code I have added indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to set a "click" event on the "content" area so that whenever anything within it is clicked on, it causes the menu to be hidden again:

```
$(".content").click(function(e) {
  bodyEl.removeClass('active-nav');
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  var bodyEl = $('nav'),
    navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

  navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(".content").click(function(e) {
    bodyEl.removeClass('active-nav');
  });
  
  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("nav").removeClass("active-nav");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #036;
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.active-nav {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-toggle-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #666;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #ccf;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.active-nav .content {
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}

.fa-bars {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <h1>This is content</h1>
</div>
```

P.S. I rearranged the rest of your JavaScript slightly to all be within a "ready" block, I wasn't sure what the logic of it was previously.

P.P.S. Your demo contained jQuery twice. This is both unnecessary and can also lead to unpredictable issues. I've removed the older version in my demo above.

Answer (score 0):

SERBIAN: Jednostavno samo dodaj ovo na kraju svoje skripte:

ENG: Just add this at the end of your script:

```
$('div').click(function(){
$('nav').removeClass("active-nav");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to attach an onclick event handler to document.

```js
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

$(function() {    
    var bodyEl = $('nav'),
    navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');
        
    navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
        bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).closest(bodyEl).length && bodyEl.hasClass('active-nav')) {
            bodyEl.removeClass('active-nav');
        }
    });

});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("nav").removeClass("active-nav");
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #036;
    transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.active-nav{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.nav-toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width:50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #666;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 300px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #ccf;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.active-nav .content {
    transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}
.fa-bars{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</script>
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <h1>This is content</h1>
</div>
```